# How does function symexist work?

Tags: sas

I suppose symexist is used for checking macro variables (local ones). I made a test but the output is out of my expectation. The code is:

```
%macro test(t1,t2);
%if %symexist(t1) %then %put &t1. is exist;
%if %symexist(t2) %then %put &t2. is exist;
%mend;
%test(test1,);
```

The output is:

```
test1 is exist
is exist
```

Looking at the mlogic:  %IF condition %symexist(t2) is TRUE. 
There is no macro variable for t2. How it comes for TRUE? Anyone come explain how symexist works? I had a search but did not find.

Thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use &t1 not t1 because you want to test for the existence of test1 not the existence of t1.

It will still error out though, because the macro variable t2 doesn't exist.

```
%let test1 = Yes;

%macro test(t1, t2);
    %if %symexist(&t1) %then
        %put &t1. is exist;

    %if %symexist(&t2) %then
        %put &t2. is exist;
    %else
        %put &t2. does not exist;
%mend;

%test(test1, test2);
```

The output will be:

> test1 is exist
>
> test2 does not exist

Answer (score 3):

There are macro variables named T1 and T2 because you defined them by making them parameters to your macro.  All macro parameters are local macro variables to the macro.